# Callin a function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am looking to get data from steam api. This is what my server.js looks like.

I get the steamID from the `req.query` thing. Then I want them passed to the function as the last part of the url string.

So far I've tested the following: forced the key directly into the `var url` and removed the function. It worked.

I tried to create a `var rekt` after the `req.query`, and passed it like `getData(rekt)`. It didn't work.

So I think calling of the function doesn't work because there is a different syntax for this in node js(as I'm new in it.) Hopefully it's enough information.

```
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var gotSteamID;

app.use(express.static('site'));

app.get('/data.html', function(req, res){ 
    gotSteamID = req.query.SteamID;
    getData(gotSteamID);
}); 

function getData(gotSteamID) {
    app.get('/steam/stats', function(httpRequest, httpResponse) {
        var url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=IREMOVEDTHEKEY&steamid=' + gotSteamID;
        request.get(url, function(error, steamHttpResponse, steamHttpBody) {
            httpResponse.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            httpResponse.send(steamHttpBody);
        });
    });
}

var port = 4000;
var server = app.listen(port);
```

and the html post looks like

```html
<form class="form" action="data.html" method="GET">
                <input type="text" name="SteamID" placeholder="76561198101455802" id="steamIDvalue" name="selectpicker" required>
                <a href="data.html"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="&#10140" onclick="getValue()" id="rekt"></a>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it looks like you're attempting to setup another endpoint (via [`app.get()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get.method)) in your request handler for `/data.html`. With that removed, your `request.get()` will now be invoked.

### Using query params

The following should allow you to make GET requests to `/data`. I removed the `.html` since you're actually serving JSON from this endpoint (you'll want to change this in your form)

```
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('site'));

var appid = 730;
var key = 'IREMOVEDTHEKEY';
var api = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/';

app.get('/data', function(req, res){ 
  var steamId = req.query.SteamID;
  var url = api + '?appid='+ appid +'&key='+ key +'&steamid=' + steamId;
  request.get(url, function(error, response, body) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(body);
  });
}); 

app.listen(4000);
```

### Using URL params

If you'd like to move away from using a query param, you could use something like the following:

```
app.get('/steam/stats/:steamId', function(req, res){ 
  var steamId = req.params.steamId;
  var url = api + '?appid='+ appid +'&key='+ key +'&steamid=' + steamId;
  request.get(url, function(error, response, body) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(body);
  });
});
```

#### Cleaning up your Request

String concatenation is nice, but [request](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) offers a more convenient (and easier to read/maintain) way to create your API URL.

> `qs` - object containing querystring values to be appended to the uri

If you broke out your `appid` and `key` as I did above, you can pass them to qs without having to worry about `?` and `&` URL management.

```
request.get({
  url: api,
  qs: {
    appid: appid,
    key: key,
    steamid: req.params.steamId
  }
});
```

Just a friendly tidbit to help tidy up your code and save you from some potential frustration down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the 2 app.get (one inside the function), why don't you expose 1 API call that gets the ID in the parameter?

```
app.get('/steam/stats/:id', function(httpRequest, httpResponse) {
    var url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=IREMOVEDTHEKEY&steamid=' + id;
    request.get(url, function(error, steamHttpResponse, steamHttpBody) {
        httpResponse.json(steamHttpBody);
    });
});
```

Then in the html, you need to call /steam/stats/id instead of /data.html?SteamId=xxx